# How can I save bug reports from my Android device to my local storage using ES or any other app?

Tags: logging, bugs, es-file-explorer

When I take a bug report (e.g. through the power menu, after this option has been enabled in Settings), a notification appears and after tapping this, I get a number of options to complete the action. I can send the bug report using Gmail, save it to Dropbox, etc. All of these work fine. However what I would really like to do is to save it to my local storage. I tried to use "ES Save To" for this, part of ES File Explorer. But when I tried to do it, I got an error "This operation is not supported".

I figure that if it's possible to save bug reports into the cloud, it must be technically possible to save them to local storage. Does anyone know why "ES Save To" does not work for this, and could recommend how to achieve this goal?

I'm using Android 5.0 and I'm just saving to something on the normal internal storage, not external SD card or anything like that.